# Empty lambda expression on same line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, code-formatting

Per default, IntelliJ 15.0.3 puts the closing brace of an empty lambda expression on the next line when reformatting the code.

```
Consumer<String> myFunc= aString -> {
};
```

In my opinion this is slightly detrimental to code readability and I want to keep the empty lambda expression on the same line:

```
Consumer<String> myFunc= aString -> {};
```

Where can I find the setting to change this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's in `Settings` (shortcut is <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) under`Editor` ›  `Code Style` › `Java` › `Wrapping and Braces` › `Keep when reformatting` › `Simple lambdas in one line`:

[image: intellij settings]